# Gradle task dependsOn already executed task

Tags: gradle, task

If taskB depends on taskA, when I execute task A and then taskB...

Question 1: Is taskA executed just once?
Question 2: Is it executed when I run taskA or when I run taskB?

Comment: Show your gradle file.

Comment: when you call taskB gradle will run taskA only if gradle decides that it is not up to date. the same happens when you run taskA alone - if gradle decides it is up to date nothing gets executed. without more details it is however impossible to tell you why gradle could consider taskA as up to date. **TL;DR - RTFM**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Gradle task will **only** be executed **once** in a build (Gradle invocation).

Also, the task order you pass to Gradle will only be maintained, if there are no dependencies between them:

If you call `gradle taskA taskB`, but `taskA.dependsOn taskB`, `taskB` will be executed before `taskA`.